# Synchronizing Voice and Text on Botframework V4

Tags: botframework, web-chat

I'm using Direct Line, MS Speech Service and Webchat on bot running on Botframework V4.
The application is fully voice based and is working fine.
However, the text and voice motion is not in sync.
In other words, after the first text+voice interaction, the next text is displayed before the previous speech service has been finished - so on and so forth.
Hence, voice is always delayed in relation to the text motion.
I was wondering if webchat.js would be able to automatically orchestrate that or there is another way to accomplish it.
Thx in advance.
Bot client call code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>FTD Bit_Bot</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #fff; background-image: url('../img/FTDBackgroundStaging.jpg');">
    <div id="chatbot" role="main"
         data-cb-width="320px"
         data-cb-height="400px"
         data-cb-border="1px solid #ededed"
         data-cb-border-radius="0px"
         data-cb-background-color="white"
         data-cb-position="fixed"
         data-cb-right="40px"
         data-cb-bottom="100px"
         data-cb-zIndex="1"
         data-cb-bubble-background="rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.15)"
         data-cb-bubble-from-user-background="#e22e2c"
         data-cb-bubble-from-user-text-color="white"
         data-cb-bubble-max-width="600"
         data-cb-bot-avatar-image="http://demo.radical-thinking.net/bella/microsoft/chat-assets/img/Chat-in-day-Workshop-Icon.png"
         data-cb-hide-send-box="false"
         data-cb-hide-upload-button="true"
         data-cb-send-box-button-color="#e22e2c"
         data-cb-send-box-button-color-on-disabled="#CCC"
         data-cb-send-box-button-color-on-focus="#333"
         data-cb-send-box-button-color-on-hover="#333"
         data-cb-send-box-height="30"
         data-cb-suggested-action-text-color="black"
         data-cb-suggested-action-border="solid 2px #e22e2c"
         data-cb-suggested-action-height="30">
    </div>
    <!-- Include ajax library for speech service token request call -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include webchat client functionality (https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) -->
    <!-- Change to the latest directory to stop the 'No renderer for this activity' error. However the avatar won't show -->
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script>
        var chatbot = document.getElementById('chatbot');

        // Style modifications
        const styleOptions = {

            // Colors
            bubbleBackground: chatbot.dataset.cbBubbleBackground,
            bubbleFromUserBackground: chatbot.dataset.cbBubbleFromUserBackground,
            bubbleFromUserTextColor: chatbot.dataset.cbBubbleFromUserTextColor,
            bubbleMaxWidth: parseInt(chatbot.dataset.cbBubbleMaxWidth), // maximum width of text message

            // Avatar
            //avatarSize: 100,
            //botAvatarImage: 'https://i.imgur.com/7YwR4wK.png',
            botAvatarImage: chatbot.dataset.cbBotAvatarImage,
            //botAvatarInitials: 'Bot',
            //userAvatarImage: '',
            userAvatarInitials: '',

            // Send box
            hideSendBox: JSON.parse(chatbot.dataset.cbHideSendBox),
            hideUploadButton: JSON.parse(chatbot.dataset.cbHideUploadButton),
            sendBoxButtonColor: chatbot.dataset.cbSendBoxButtonColor,
            sendBoxButtonColorOnDisabled: chatbot.dataset.cbSendBoxButtonColorOnDisabled,
            sendBoxButtonColorOnFocus: chatbot.dataset.cbSendBoxButtonColorOnFocus,
            sendBoxButtonColorOnHover: chatbot.dataset.cbSendBoxButtonColorOnHover,
            sendBoxHeight: parseInt(chatbot.dataset.cbSendBoxHeight),

            // Suggested actions
            suggestedActionTextColor: chatbot.dataset.cbSuggestedActionTextColor,
            suggestedActionBorder: chatbot.dataset.cbSuggestedActionBorder,
            suggestedActionHeight: parseInt(chatbot.dataset.cbSuggestedActionHeight),

        }
    </script>
    <script>
        var chatbot = document.getElementById("chatbot");

        //style tag start
        var script = {
            id: 'chatbotStyle',
            type: 'text/css',
            style: document.createElement('style'),
            content: '@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,600"); ::-webkit-scrollbar{width:10px}::-webkit-scrollbar-track{background:#f1f1f1}::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{background:#888}::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{background:#555} #chatbot{ font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; position: fixed; right: 10px; bottom: 20px; text-align: center; } #chatbot img{ margin: auto; } #chatbot small{ display: block; font-size: 9px; } .initLaunchPad{ cursor: pointer; text-align: center; transition: .4s all; } .botHeader{min-height:40px;background:#ededed;border-radius:6px 6px 0 0;display:flex;justify-content:space-between;align-items:center;padding:4px} .botHeader img{float:left;width:32px;height:32px; border-radius:50%;background-color:#f9f9f9}.botHeader h5{float:left;padding:0!important;margin:4px 0 3px 6px} .botHeader h5 small{font-size: 12px;} .botHeader > div{width:40%;display:flex;align-items:center;text-align:left;height:32px} #botClose{cursor:pointer;font-size:12px;font-weight:600;padding:6px 8px;border-radius:4px;background-color:#e22e2c;color:#fff; } #botContainer{ display: none; border-radius: 8px; border:1px solid #cbcbcb; transition:.4s all; width: 310px; height: 420px; max-width:420px; max-height: 420px; margin-bottom: 4px; } #botBody{ height: 366px; } ',
            append: function () {
                this.style.type = this.type;
                this.style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.content));
                document.head.appendChild(this.style);
            }
        }; script.append();
        //style tag end

        //initLaunchPad started
        var initLaunchPad = document.createElement('div');
        initLaunchPad.classList.add('initLaunchPad');
        var initBotIcon = document.createElement('img');
        initBotIcon.src = "https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4876/39891228293_13c532f352_o.gif";
        initBotIcon.width = 86;
        initLaunchPad.appendChild(initBotIcon);
        chatbot.appendChild(initLaunchPad);       

        $(function getSpeechAuthToken() {
            var params = {
                // Request parameters
            };

            $.ajax({
                url: "https://brazilsouth.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issuetoken" + $.param(params),
                beforeSend: function (xhrObj) {
                    // Request headers
                    xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "XXXXXXXX");
                },
                type: "POST",
                // Request body
                data: "{body}",
            })
                .done(function (data) {
                    speechAuthToken = data;
                })
                .fail(function () {
                    alert("error");
                });
        });
        initBotIcon.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            initLaunchPad.style.display = "none";
            botContainer.style.display = "block";

            /*Call bot API*/
            (async function () {
                // In this demo, we are using Direct Line token from MockBot.
                // To talk to your bot, you should use the token exchanged using your Direct Line secret.
                // You should never put the Direct Line secret in the browser or client app.
                // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-authentication
                //const res = await fetch('https://webchat-mockbot.azurewebsites.net/directline/token', { method: 'POST' });
                //const { token } = await res.json();
                // To run this demo, you can either use our authorization token, or provide your own subscription key thru ?s=BING_SPEECH_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY

                const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
                //const subscriptionKey = searchParams.get('s');

                //Speech Service Token Generation
                const subscriptionKey = 'XXXXXXXX';
                const region = 'brazilsouth';
                let webSpeechPonyfillFactory;

                //Speech Service Setting
                webSpeechPonyfillFactory = await window.WebChat.createCognitiveServicesSpeechServicesPonyfillFactory({
                    credentials: {
                        authorizationToken: speechAuthToken,
                        region: region
                    }
                });

                //Direct-Line BotToken Generation

                const res = await fetch('https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate', { method: 'POST', headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + 'XXXXXXXX' } });
                const { token } = await res.json();
                //***
                // Pass a Web Speech ponyfill factory to renderWebChat.
                // You can also use your own speech engine given it is compliant to W3C Web Speech API, https://w3c.github.io/speech-api/.
                // For implementor, look at createBrowserWebSpeechPonyfill.js for details.

                //Bot Service Setting
                //WebSpeechPonyfillFactory refernece at https://github.com/compulim/web-speech-cognitive-services
                //Mock-up bot reference code at https://github.com/compulim/BotFramework-MockBot
                window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
                    directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }),
                    store,
                    userID: "User",
                    styleOptions,
                    locale: 'pt-BR',
                    selectVoice: (voices, activity) =>
                        activity.locale === 'pt-BR'
                            ? voices.find(({ name }) => /Daniel/iu.test(name))
                            : voices.find(({ name }) => /Daniel/iu.test(name)) ||
                            voices.find(({ name }) => /Daniel/iu.test(name)),
                    webSpeechPonyfillFactory
                }, document.getElementById('botBody'));
                document.querySelector('#botBody > *').focus();

                var mainTag = chatbot.getElementsByClassName('main')[0];
                mainTag.style.borderTop = chatbot.dataset.cbBorder;
            })().catch(err => console.error(err));

            //Bot Message Exchange Setting 
            const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
                if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
                    dispatch({
                        type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
                        payload: {
                            name: 'studentName',
                            value: 'Amintas'
                        }
                    });
                    dispatch({
                        type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
                        payload: {
                            name: 'studentGender',
                            value: 'Male'
                        }
                    });
                    dispatch({
                        type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
                        payload: {
                            name: 'activityName',
                            value: 'Acitivy2'
                        }
                    });
                }
                return next(action);
            });

            return false;
        });

        //initLaunchPad ended

        var botContainer = document.createElement('div');
        botContainer.id = "botContainer";

        var botHeader = document.createElement('div');
        botHeader.classList.add('botHeader');

        var botClose = document.createElement('a');
        botClose.id = "botClose";
        botClose.innerText = "X";
        botClose.title = "Close";
        botHeader.innerHTML = "<div><img src='" + chatbot.dataset.cbBotAvatarImage + "'/> <h5>Bit_Bot <small>FTD Educação</small> </div></h5>";
        botHeader.appendChild(botClose);

        botClose.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            initLaunchPad.style.display = "";
            botContainer.style.display = "none";
            return false;
        });

        botContainer.appendChild(botHeader);

        var botBody = document.createElement('div');
        botBody.id = "botBody";
        botContainer.appendChild(botBody);

        var poweredBy = document.createElement('div');
        poweredBy.innerHTML = "<small>Powered by <img src='http://ainetw.com/img/icon.png' width=12 /> AI Networks</small>";

        chatbot.appendChild(botContainer);
        chatbot.appendChild(poweredBy);
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```